# Are there methods of adding more touch spells to a Duskblade's spell list?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, character-creation, touch-attacks

I want to play a duskblade, because their ability to channel touch range spells presents a way to use spells in melee combat. But their short list of spells (coupled with very few touch range damage spells) is kind of disheartening.

Are there any ways to add spells to that list to bolster its lack of touch range damage spells.

Using an online reference I looked at the available spells and only 1 or 2 each level were at a range of touch that also deal damage.

So too does the lack of spells known worry me but I believe that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Traditional ways of adding to spell lists include Arcane Disciple feat, gaining Domains, and the Rainbow Servant and/or Sandshaper prestige classes. Not sure how many touch-range spells you can get from those, though.

Comment: Can you also tell us a bit about what you find lacking in the existing list? "More is better" is one way to solve the problem, but you might be overlooking "this one specific thing will fix everything" as a solution. So please do include what you feel is lacking from the list, apart from mere quantity.

Comment: most of the duskblades spell list is self buffs. very few spells on its available list are touch ranged damage spells. there are quite a few ranged touches but i dont think those work with the Channeling ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of touch-range, damage-dealing spells of level 5 and below that aren't on the Duskblade list already isn't very long. At least not if you further restrict that list to "useful spells".

Anyway, there are a few well-known ways to get extra spells known/on to a general class list (there are no Duskblade-specific methods) that can be useful here:

1. The Recaster (Races of Eberron) PrC can grant any spell at all.
2. Wyrm Wizard (Dragon Magic) can grant any spell at all.
3. The Extra Spell feat (Complete Arcane) can grant any spell at all - if it works at all. That latter point is often debated.
4. Domains grant spells known. The most general, easily accessible way to get some Domain access on an arcane spellcasting class is probably the Arcane Disciple feat (Complete Divine), although that carries heavy limitations. Depending on the specific domain, you may be able to get access through a PrC.

Now, then there is the question of what spells you actually *want*.

- Combust (Spell Compendium) is a rather good spell, scales well with metamagic. Methods: 1, 2 and 3.
- Wracking touch (Spell Compendium) is OK if you have lots of Sneak Attack damage somehow. Methods: 1, 2 and 3.
- Belker Claws (Spell Compendium) are rather bad but cool. Methods: 1, 2 and 3.
- Bestow Wound (Heroes of Horror) is a cool but kind of expensive way to heal. Methods: 1, 2, 3 and 4 (Spite domain).
- The Inflict X Wounds line of spells is bad. You can get a few of them via method 4 (Destruction domain, probably others). There are at least a few more that qualify (like Parching Touch from Sandstorm), but I don't know of more worth mentioning.

Harm would be great here, but I don't know of a way to get it as a 5th level spell.

But, at the bottom line... I don't think it's worth the opportunity cost in any of these cases. Maybe for Combust, but Duskblades are rather build-constrained as it is.

Comment: Sand shaper from *Sandstorm* adds a whopping **43** spells known. At the least, it grants *parching touch* which is quite good for a duskblade.

Answer (score 3):

**Multiclass into cleric**. Really. I saw the DB spell list as being deliberately sub-par. Cleric spells, with that ability, truly own.

I ran a DB/Cleric at tenth level. Power attack, leap attack and a two-handed weapon. My only regret with that character was going 5/5, because he would have been so much cooler with 7 levels of cleric instead.

Doesn't address how to handle their low-key spell list but it is the solution I've found to DB spell selection issues.

Alternatively, as @Ernir has mentioned, you could drop DB and go with the Ordained Champion from *Complete Champion.* I really believe that if you're channeling spells through your weapon you want it to be cleric-y spells, though. Versatility, variety and some nice effects.

Comment: The Duskblade is just a handicap on a Duskblade/Cleric multiclass. For Clericy spell-channeling, a Cleric/Ordained Champion is usually the way to go.

Comment: Ordained Champion is from Complete Champion.

Comment: it is viable and quite good, but cleric is lets just say not an option i wish to pursue at the moment. too many people would expect all my spells prepped to be Healing spells. or the ocasional Buff. I do not enjoy the Healer Role. I really do not.

Comment: @Novian Call it a crusader-knight and tell them you don't do healing spells.

Comment: The 3rd-level duskblade version of Arcane Channeling is worthless; three lost spellcasting levels is not worth it for just adding weapon damage to a spell. Plus, you could get much the same effect by just using unarmed strikes to deliver the spell, instead. The 13th-level duskblade version, on the other hand, is awesome, but it’s nearly impossible to effectively combine with any other spellcasting. A duskblade/ur-priest **might** be worth something, but even then your ur-priest spellcasting is going to offer **very** few spell slots to use with Arcane Channeling.

Answer (score 2):

### Ultimate Magus

This prestige allows you to progress a spontaneous arcane class (i.e. duskblade) with an arcane class that prepares spells (i.e. wizards). But the real benefit is that you can add a few spells you know from the class that prepare spells to the spells known of the spontaneous class; at the 4th level of the prestige class you can add a 2nd level spell (I suggest Combust) and you can use the spell slots from one class to use metamagics in the spells of the other class.

Answer (score 1):

Geomancer lets you mix parameters for spells such as arcane channeling with other classes, allowing 9th level spells to be channeled if you have them.

So go 9 Duskblade, 1 Urpriest, 10 Geomancer, Urpriest being your advancing caster class. Boom, cleric arcane channeling. This also works with divine crusader but you only get one domain.