# Can a multi-class Duskblade use Arcane Channelling with cleric spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Duskblades have the ability Arcane Channelling, which allows them to cast touch spells through a melee attack with their weapon. Can they only channel Duskblade spells this way, or can they channel any touch spell they can cast (specifically, [*inflict wounds*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/inflictLightWounds.htm) from multi-classing to cleric)? Or is there something in between?

Comment: [Related] [Methods of adding more touch spells to a Duskblade's spell list?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/24452)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. And they kick a lot more butt doing so, as opposed to those low-key Duskblade spells.

Duskblades can channel "any touch spell [they] know," beginning at third level (PHB2, p.20 - thank you @BESW). I've pulled this off before and it **rocked.** *Contagion*, *bestow curse*, *inflict* and *cure* spells (the latter for undead) work decently in varying degrees, at least for starters.

Comment: Ah ha! The inflict spells allow for a save while the duskblade's don't. I suppose that doesn't make them so overwhelmingly better as I thought.

Comment: While it can be useful to spontaneously switch to *cure* or *inflict* spells as a cleric since resistances to those energy types are relatively uncommon, be careful since between the Fortitude save and the sheer lower numbers that those spells produce, you lose a **lot** when you use them. It is much better to use a d6/level touch-attack spell that the target doesn't have resistance to, if you can. In most cases, it is optimal to only cast *cure* as emergency healing, and otherwise avoid the spells entirely.